# Different results when passing a MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm as Argument to a Method

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a c# winforms application and I'm using the MetroFramework for the UI. I have a class that handles all sorts of error messages (from the UI thread and background threads) and is supposed to display them on the UI using the `MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm ErrorForm`. This `ErrorForm` is then passed to a Method called `ShowAsOverlay` that uses the form it gets to display it via ShowDialog and sets it to be owned by my `MainForm` (which is a MetroForm too).

So far it all works as expected except that `ShowAsOverlay` behaves differently in the following examples:

This works as excpected (note how I create the instance of ErrorForm in the same line where I pass it to ShowAsOverlay):

```
public static void NetworkException(string message)
{
    if (MainForm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MainForm.Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            _ = ShowAsOverlay(MainForm, new ErrorForm(message, "Network Exception"));
        });
    }
    else
    {
        _ = ShowAsOverlay(MainForm, new ErrorForm(message, "Network Exception"));
    }
}
```

However the following code does not work (or at least causes the `ShowAsOverlay` method to behave differently as the `ErrorForm` is never displayed)

```
public static void NetworkException(string message)
{
    ErrorForm myErrorForm = new ErrorForm(message, "Network Exception");
    if (MainForm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MainForm.Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            _ = ShowAsOverlay(MainForm, myErrorForm);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        _ = ShowAsOverlay(MainForm, myErrorForm);
    }
}
```

So my question is: **Why in the world would it matter if I create the `ErrorForm` at the same time when passing it as an argument vs when I create it first and then pass it?**

FYI: when I was testing it the if condition always returned true (in case it matters)
Also: I didn't check if this "bug" (or maybe feature who knows) also would happen when using the "normal" System.Windows.Forms.Form So it may be MetroFramework specific or not. I really don't know whats going on anymore. I can the code of `ShowAsOverlay()` too if you want but as I said it works fine when using the first syntax so it must be related to my `NetworkException` method I guess?

Comment: `Why in the world would it matter if I create the ErrorForm at the same time when passing it as an argument vs when I create it first and then pass it?` The two different code samples are creating the form in a different thread. Presumably you should be creating the form in the UI thread (i.e. within the Invoke).

Comment: @mjwills Oh wow I'm facepalming so hard right now. Thank you. I was so confused I didn't even think about that :D